# Removing commas from arrays in HTML [element.innerHTML]

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm having an issue with this. I'm trying to get rid of those commas. Used `varArray.join(" ")` too, but with no success. I went as far as creating a `for` loop, but it didn't work(well it might've worked, but I'm a beginner, though I doubt that).

Here's the code:

```js
let varArray = [];
let rufus1 = document.getElementById('rufus1');
let rufus2 = document.getElementById('rufus2'); // variables for easing syntax

function arrayGiver() {
  varArray.push('<div>' + document.getElementById('rufus1').value + '</div>');
  // I've used `<div>` instead of `<br>` for line breaking the elements, but when I'll be making bigger more complex projects I should probably use `<br>` shouldn't I?

  rufus2.innerHTML = ("You have just added to your collection:" + "<br/>" +
    varArray);
  //this cleans the input after executing the function
  rufus1.value = '';
}


//this makes the function execute on an enter key press
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(enterKey) {
  if (enterKey.keyCode === 13) {
    arrayGiver();
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="rufus1">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="arrayGiver();">Bleh</button>
<p id="rufus2"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because array auto add commas as separator when converted to string. You can get rid of this by simply use `join(' ')` on `varArray` as below

```js
    let varArray = [];
    let rufus1 = document.getElementById('rufus1');
    let rufus2 = document.getElementById('rufus2');
    // variables for easing syntax



    function arrayGiver() {
      varArray.push('<div>' + document.getElementById('rufus1').value + '</div>') // I've used `<div>` instead of `<br>` for line breaking the elements, but when I'll be making bigger more complex projects I should probably use `<br>` shouldn't I?

      rufus2.innerHTML = ("You have just added to your collection:" + "<br/>" +
        varArray.join(' '));
      //this cleans the input after executing the function
      rufus1.value = '';
    }


    //this makes the function execute on an enter key press
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (enterKey) {
      if (enterKey.keyCode === 13) {
        arrayGiver();
      }
    })
```

```html
  <input id="rufus1" type="text">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="arrayGiver();">Bleh</button>
  <p id="rufus2"></p>
```

Comment: What?! I literally did the same thing, and it didn't work. Maybe because I didn't put the extra space in the apostrophes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach()` or another loop to add the array elements to `innerHTML`

For this answer I used:

```
varArray.forEach(e => rufus2.innerHTML += e);
```

which iterates over the array adding each element (`e`) to `rufus2.innerHTML`.

```js
let varArray = [];
let rufus1 = document.getElementById('rufus1');
let rufus2 = document.getElementById('rufus2'); // variables for easing syntax

function arrayGiver() {
  varArray.push('<div>' + document.getElementById('rufus1').value + '</div>');
  // I've used `<div>` instead of `<br>` for line breaking the elements, but when I'll be making bigger more complex projects I should probably use `<br>` shouldn't I?

  rufus2.innerHTML = ("You have just added to your collection:" + "<br/>");
  varArray.forEach(e => rufus2.innerHTML += e);
  //this cleans the input after executing the function
  rufus1.value = '';
}


//this makes the function execute on an enter key press
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(enterKey) {
  if (enterKey.keyCode === 13) {
    arrayGiver();
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="rufus1">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="arrayGiver();">Bleh</button>
<p id="rufus2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use string variable instead of array as below

```
let varArray = [];
var list ='';
let rufus1 = document.getElementById('rufus1');
let rufus2 = document.getElementById('rufus2');
// variables for easing syntax



function arrayGiver(){
  list = list + '<div>' + document.getElementById('rufus1').value + '</div>'
  rufus2.innerHTML = ("You have just added to your collection:" + "<br/>" + list);
  list.value = '';
}
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/bvQKbX

```js
let varArray = [];
var list ='';
let rufus1 = document.getElementById('rufus1');
let rufus2 = document.getElementById('rufus2');
// variables for easing syntax

   

function arrayGiver(){
  list = list + '<div>' + document.getElementById('rufus1').value + '</div>'
  rufus2.innerHTML = ("You have just added to your collection:" + "<br/>" + list);
  list.value = '';
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(enterKey) {
  if(enterKey.keyCode === 13){
    arrayGiver();
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<input id="rufus1">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="arrayGiver();">Bleh</button>
<p id="rufus2"></p>
```

Comment: Wow, how come I didn't think of this, it would've made it so much easier!